# What is the output of this program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

when i tried to run compile and execute this statement in a simple c file:

```
main(){ printf("%d");}
```

on HP it's is giving me 64 and on AIX its giving me 804359524.

Could anyone tell me what is this behavior.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you mean:

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d");
}
```

That being the case, printf() is reading an int (as directed by the format specifier %d) from the stack. Since you've not specified one, it's just reading whatever is on the stack and using that. Hence, your seeing pseudo-random output.

Instead, try:

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d", 10101);
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 12):

This is classic [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The compiler doesn't check that you provide enough arguments to match your formatting string. There are compilers that do this ([gcc is one](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat-240)), but yours doesn't.

The code in `printf()` will happily step through its given formatting string, and when it gets to the "%d" it will read off one `int`-sized argument (typically: from the stack), not knowing there is no argument there for it to read.

Whatever value happens to be on the stack gets printed.

Answer (score 3):

Some compilers, like gcc, will catch this type of oh so common problems if you specify a high enough warning level.  Like this (compiling you code, with -Wall - all warnings) :

```
gcc    -c -g -Wall -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newmain.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newmain.o newmain.c
newmain.c: In function `main':
newmain.c:16: warning: too few arguments for format
```

This is one of around 998 good reasons to always compile with a high warning level, and to take the warning messages seriously.

Answer (score 2):

The code is exposing Undefined Behavior. On other systems it might print "Stack Overflow", (seriously!). %d tells the CRT library that you'll provide an integer, but you don't.

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get a stack overflow in that code - the stack is not growing.

Comment: The trigger for a stack overflow is typically a memory access to the stack guard page. printf() could trigger that access when it fails to read the %d integer, and instead hits the guard page. And since it's not a write, you can't solve it by adding another page. It's reasonable for an OS to print "stack overflow" whenever there's any unfixable stack guard page violation; it'll be 99% correct

Comment: I think that in this case, the value printed is going to be either the return address from the printf function, a register value or perhaps something from main's stack frame depending on the implementation of the compiler and the OS it's running on. I always thought a 'stack overflow' was when the stack had run out of memory when trying to store data on the stack, never when reading data.

Comment: If we assume the C ABI (where parameters are pushed onto the stack right to left). The skizz is correct and it is unlikely to produce a stack overflow (more likely the return address). But that's a big assumption.

Comment: Not a big assumption, the question is tagged C and C++.

Comment: "_The_ C ABI" - is there such a thing? Many platforms define one, which is pretty much proof to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you compile

```
main(){ printf("%d");}
```

This will pick a random value off the current stack. Try this:

```
main() {
   printf("%d", 0);
   printf("%d");
}
```

Now, the second `printf()` will always print `0` since it gets the same stack as the first call.

[EDIT] This doesn't work on x86 Linux with GCC 4.1.2. Here is the generated assembler code (use `gcc -S -o t.s t.c`):

```
    movl    $0, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
```

As you can see, the second argument isn't pushed on the stack but passed via `%esi` (which is a register). That same register is probably modified in `printf()` which is why it's losing its value. Damn optimizations ;)

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if you'd get 1. printf returns the number of arguments consumed. This return value could overwrite the stack.

Comment: I doubt that for two reasons: a) On most machines, the return value is in a register and b) it would overwrite the format string if it was passed on the stack if it wasn't saved in a different place by the ABI.

Comment: Aaron, running that with the intel icc compiler gives a warning about the second printf and an output of 04204818 (0 and 4204818)

Comment: @Glen: Odd. The second printf() should use the same stack addresses as the first and I see no reason to overwrite the second argument :/ Do you have "mungwall" options active or something that trashes unused memory?

Comment: @AAron, no special options were turned on. ">icc x.cc" where x.cc just has the above code.